# Using JPA1.0: How to write queries

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpa-1.0

Good day,

I have this weird problem:

This following statement works

Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT m from AccountClass as m");

whereas this following statement does not

Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT m from AccountClass");

I'm trying to write a statement that allows me to use the where clause;

thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`em.createQuery`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29)  expects a JPQL query and not a SQL query to be passed as a parameter.

`SELECT m FROM AccountClass` is not a valid JPQL query, where as `SELECT m FROM AccountClass m` is valid. If you wish to learn further about JPQL, you can start with the [Java EE tutorial chapter on JPQL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html).

The reason why `SELECT m FROM AccountClass as m` works in this case, is because `AS` is an optional keyword. If you wish to issue a WHERE clause, it is trivial to do so - `SELECT m FROM AccountClass m WHERE m.x= :param1`, where `x` is an attribute of the `AccountClass` class and `param1` is a named parameter whose value has to be set using the [`Query.setParameter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method.